# get the time difference in datetimeindex in pandas dataframe and re-index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to read .nc files into pandas dataframe. The timestamp in the nc file is the middle of the time interval when we measuring the data. However, I want to get the end of the time interval. So first I get the time difference in datetimeindex and divided by 2 and add it to the old timestamp. Then re-index the data with new timestamp.
The result from the following python code is quite close to what I'd expected. But there are still two problems remaining to be solved.

1. how to avoid the floats in the seconds and round it into integers?
2. the first timestamp is NaT, is there any way to make it appear as datetime automatically? (it should be 2007-11-30 20:40:09).

Any suggestions are welcome!

**My python code:**

```
nc_files_to_open = glob.glob(r'root\*\*\200*.nc', recursive=True)

df = xr.open_mfdataset(nc_files_to_open).to_dataframe()

df.index = df.index + df.index.to_series().diff()/2
```

the result from the 'old' df:

```
                         X
time
2007-11-30 20:20:39           6
2007-11-30 20:59:39           5
2007-11-30 21:38:38           4
2007-11-30 22:17:38           3
2007-11-30 22:56:38           2
```

the result from the 'new' df:

```
                         X
time                                            
NaT                               6
2007-11-30 21:19:09.000           5
2007-11-30 21:58:07.500           4
2007-11-30 22:37:08.000           3
2007-11-30 23:16:08.000           2


print(df.index)


DatetimeIndex(...
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', length=5, freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `fillna` and `ceil`:

```
df.index = df.index + df.index.to_series().diff()/2
df.index = df.index.fillna(pd.to_datetime('2007-11-30 20:40:09')).ceil(freq='s')
```

---

```
                        X
time    
2007-11-30 20:40:09     6
2007-11-30 21:19:09     5
2007-11-30 21:58:08     4
2007-11-30 22:37:08     3
2007-11-30 23:16:08     2
```